# Ctrl + Alt + Num 0 Doesn't work

Tags: rendering, camera

I've followed the doughnut blender tutorial on youtube step by step, but when it comes to rendering, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> doesn't do anything.

I'm not sure if I changed something by accident, but even doing it manually doesn't work. I've looked up the problem and haven't found anything similar. I don't know what else to do, this is the first time I'm working with Blender.[image]
[image]

Comment: You're already in your camera's perspective, as indicated in the top left corner of the viewport. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You should choose a camera if I not mistake

Comment: It shouldn't matter what object is selected, start blender with [factory settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/defaults.html#loading-factory-settings) and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this feature to *[Quick Favorites](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html?highlight=quick%20favorites#quick-favorites)* you can follow these steps:

- Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to search for commands and type "active camera"
- Right-click <kbd>RMB</kbd> on *Align active Camera to View* and select *Add to Quick Favorites*
- Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to get the list of favorite commands and you can quickly select the *Align Command* from that list

---

Otherwise you can also follow these steps to quickly enable lock of the camera view:

#### Step 1

Press <kbd>N</kbd> in the *3d View* to open up the right [sidebar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/sidebar.html#sidebar) and go to *View*:

[image]

#### Step 2

Right-click <kbd>RMB</kbd> on *Camera to view* and Select *Add to Quick Favorites*:

[image]

Now you can enable *Camera to View* by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Blender 3.0. If you are on a Windows laptop computer with limited keyboard keys, you can emulate desktop numpad.

On you top screen click on *Edit> Preference> Input* under *Keyboard*, check *Emulate Numpad*.