# Icons missing and not generating in the asset library for objects in a collection

Tags: asset-browser, asset

I am currently experiencing an issue with Blender's asset library where icons for objects in a collection are not automatically generating. Usually, the icons are generated automatically, but in this case, I have multiple objects attached to an empty to keep them together, and then they are placed in a collection. The collection is marked as an asset.

The issue I'm facing is that the icons for these assets will only generate if I manually click on each one and hit "Generate Preview". However, with several thousand assets, this process becomes incredibly tedious and time-consuming.

I'm wondering if anyone else has faced this issue or has any suggestions for how I can get Blender to automatically generate icons for all of the objects in the collection without having to manually generate previews for each one.

Blender version: 3.1 > 3.5[mainly 3.5 now.]
Operating System: Windows 10

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: New Asset library, no thumbnails gennerating]

[image: Asset with manually generated thumbnail]

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+numpad+0` = camera to view (will create thumbnails correctly after saving)

Have the thumbnails been created?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185532/ctrl-alt-num-0-doesnt-work

Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIpysY8DEFI